# How could I echo a random database field once a week using php and mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Google hasn't been much help sadly. I have some pseudo code below to give you an idea of what I'd like to achieve:

```
if ($time == one week) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table RANDOMLY,$connection");
  echo $result[0];
}
```

I know I should be using mysqli, but I'm augumenting an existing (ageing) system. I'll be utilising mysqli in future, so if you could give me the solution using mysql that would be great!

Comment: Are you wanting to select a random column or a random table? or both?

Comment: Sorry, I want to select a random column from a single table.

Comment: Please provide your table schema.

Comment: I'm no MySQL expert but perhaps you can do something with `SHOW COLUMNS` take a look at this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @moonwave99 Here are my table headings:


  
id | 
uid | 
name | 
description | 
type | 
imgpath |

Comment: @j0k I know, I know, I know mysql functions are the antichrist, and will be updating in future. This is just a temporary solution. Thanks for the PDO tutorial.

Comment: @JWH you want a random **column** or a random **row**? A random row is trivial [google for `mysql rand() limit 0,1`], a random column seems pointless and insecure [print all IDs - yay!].

Comment: @j0k Indeed it does! Random row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done with a single statement.

My best guess would be to use [`mysql_list_tables`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php), select a random entry from that list and continue from there on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps generating a random number between 1 and the value of `SELECT Count(ID) from table`. Then you have the index of the value you wish to output, you can simply run a SELECT statement for it; and output! :)